# pyspark Dataframe into partitioned Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, partition

I have a table in Hive like following:

```
hive> create table if not exists stock_quote (TradeDay string, TradeTime string, OpenPrice string, HighPrice string, LowPrice String, ClosePrice String, volume string) partitioned by (tickerid string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;
```

Trying to insert into the table by following code:

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
lines = sc.textFile('file:///<File Name>')
rows = lines.map(lambda line : line.split(','))
rows_map = rows.map(lambda row : Row(tickerid = row[0], tradeday = row[1], tradetime = row[2],
                                    openprice = row[3], highprice = row[4],
                                    lowprice = row[5], closeprice = row[6],
                                    volume = row[7]))
rows_df = spark.createDataFrame(rows_map)
rows_df.write.format('hive').mode('append').partitionBy('tickerid').saveAsTable('stock_quote')
```

Getting following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.saveAsTable.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Requested partitioning does not match the stock_quote table:
Requested partitions: 
Table partitions: tickerid
```

Tried with following:

```
stock_quote_table = namedtuple("stock_quote", 
                               ["tickerid", "tradeday", "tradetime", "openprice", "highprice", "lowprice", "closeprice", "volume"])
rows_map = rows.map(lambda row : stock_quote_table(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7]))
rows_df = spark.createDataFrame(rows_map)
rows_df.write.mode('append').partitionBy('tickerid').insertInto('default.stock_quote')
```

Got the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "insertInto() can't be used together with partitionBy(). Partition columns have already been defined for the table. It is not necessary to use partitionBy().;"
```

So changed the last line:

```
rows_df.write.mode('append').insertInto('default.stock_quote')
```

Above inserted data into table, but it created one sub-directory for each line in the file under HDFS with tickerid= like /user/hive/warehouse/stock_quote/tickerid=980 and under that, file name starting with 'part...'

Please suggest what is going wrong in the code.

Comment: If you partition by unique field, then single file per `Row` is expected. What you need for high cardinality fields is `bucketBy`. The second error is self-explanatory - `partitionBy` clause is not allowed (or necessary) with writes to partitioned table.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Guess I didn't specify sufficient details. So all rows in the file has same 'tickerid'. Still there are multiple files for every row.

Comment: Any suggestion please...